# JavaFX TableView only populating some columns

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to populate a TableView in JavaFX, but only one of the columns is being populated with Data. I've been following the oracle documentation and think that my name conventions are correct.

Data Model:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

public class PeakClassification {

private final SimpleIntegerProperty peakStart;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty peakEnd;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty peakMaxima;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty peakHeight;
private final SimpleIntegerProperty peakWidth;

    public PeakClassification(int peakStart, int peakEnd, int peakMaxima, int peakHeight) {
        this.peakStart = new SimpleIntegerProperty(peakStart);
        this.peakEnd = new SimpleIntegerProperty(peakEnd);
        this.peakMaxima = new SimpleIntegerProperty(peakMaxima);
        this.peakHeight = new SimpleIntegerProperty(peakHeight);
        this.peakWidth = new SimpleIntegerProperty(peakEnd - peakStart);
    }

  public int getPeakWidth() {
      return peakWidth.get();
  } 

  public int getPeakHeight() {
      return peakHeight.get();
  }

  public int getPeakStart() {
      return peakStart.get();
  }

  public int getPeakEnd() {
      return peakEnd.get();
  }

  public int getPeakMaxima() {
      return peakMaxima.get();
  }
}
```

Code for creating the table:

```
 //instantiate the table
    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    //start values
    TableColumn startValue = new TableColumn("Start pos");
    startValue.setMinWidth(100);
    startValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PeakClassification, Integer>("peakStart"));

    TableColumn maximumValue = new TableColumn("Max pos");
    startValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PeakClassification, Integer>("peakMaxima"));



    tableView.setItems(peakClassifications);

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(startValue, maximumValue);
```

I've printed out the `peakClassifications` list to console to verify that the maximumValue isn't null.

The getter for the `peakMaxima` field is `getPeakMaxima()` so it should be able to find it. I've looked at other stackoverflow entries and that seems to be the issue in most of the cases.

Here's a snippet of the result:

[image]

Its probably an obvious mistake. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Copy and paste error... you set the cell value factory for `startValue` twice.

Comment: Yep, that'd do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Error is here, you mistankenly used `startValue` variable again instead of `maximumValue`

```
TableColumn maximumValue = new TableColumn("Max pos");
startValue.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<PeakClassification, Integer>("peakMaxima"));
```